# JavaScript Synch Function before AJAX / jQuery / etc. library - Can't recall implementation, any advice

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

It's been many years (~10) since I've done any JavaScript development and now that I'm getting back into some JS development, it is truly amazing the state of affairs.  It seems there are tons of libraries out there.

Well, here's my question, I remember we used to do asynchronous JS function calls using XmlHttlRequests.  I remember the we used to write explicit functions by listening to states like =4 and so on.  In hindsight, seems like very low-level JS compared to some of the stuff I'm seeing nowadays.

Current problem, I'm consuming a JS function from a 3rd party API that is synchronous.  Is there any way I can make it asynchronous, if it doesn't have a "callback" parameter, w/o the original API author changing?  Any wrapper, pattern, or any of these new libraries could do this?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which library you're using but [jQuery's AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) provides an option called **async** which specifies whether to do the call asynchronously (default is true).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not constrained to any specific library so any suggestions will do.  I basically just want to turn a simple JS function in an API from synch to asynch, e.g. GetEmployeeData(x1, x2, x3).  How can I turn GetEmployeeData() to an asynchronous function?

Comment: Javascript is asynchronous by default.  You just need to use a [callback function](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) to get the result asynchronously.

Comment: Terry, thanks for your response, but I'm relatively certain that JS is NOT asynchronous by default.  In the old days, it certain wasn't until objects like XMLHttpRequest came about and iframes.